# Stripe checkout session integration with firebase top-level-await error

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

Hi I've been trying to create a checkout session using the stripe firebase extension and I ran across this error:

./pages/viewer.js
Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/next/dist/build/babel/loader/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)

I'm not sure what the error is referring to. It's a whole new concept to me.

I'm using the next.js framework

My Code:

firebase.js file:

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAIbAZGEmnB5EMpj7TTR0v0yjK2c1EYJzo",
  authDomain: "comics-app-a4675.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "comics-app-a4675",
  storageBucket: "comics-app-a4675.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "963431498351",
  appId: "1:963431498351:web:e1b078045362f3c168039a"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Viewer.js file (Page i'm using as the success url):

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Reader from '../components/Reader';
import Header from "../components/Header";
import Feed from "../components/Feed";
import Titles from "../components/Titles"
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { getApp } from "@firebase/app";
import { getStripePayments } from "@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments";
import { getProducts } from "@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments";
import { createCheckoutSession } from "@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments";
import { onCurrentUserSubscriptionUpdate } from "@stripe/firestore-stripe-payments";

const app = getApp();
const payments = getStripePayments(app, {
  productsCollection: "products",
  customersCollection: "customers",
});

const products = await getProducts(payments, {
  includePrices: true,
  activeOnly: true,
});
for (const product of products) {
  // ...
}

const session = await createCheckoutSession(payments, {
  price: myPriceId,
});
window.location.assign(session.url);

onCurrentUserSubscriptionUpdate(
  payments,
  (snapshot) => {
    for (const change in snapshot.changes) {
      if (change.type === "added") {
        console.log(`New subscription added with ID: ${change.subscription.id}`);
      }
    }
  }
);
function viewer() {
 
 


return (
        <div>
         <Head>
        <title>Minerva</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
     
        <Header />
          <Reader />  
          
          <div className="pl-28 m-8 text-white">
       <h1 className="text-2xl font-extrabold">Metroid, Chapter 2</h1>
        <p className="font-bold border-b">September 21st, 2021</p>
      </div> 
        
        <Feed />
       
        </div>
    )
}

export default viewer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have `topLevelAwait` enabled inside your next.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.experiments = config.experiments || {}
    config.experiments.topLevelAwait = true
    return config
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks I did not have that code in my next.config.js file before. But its still giving me the same error

Comment: try deleting your .next build folder also you can read this discussion about this issue https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/11185#discussioncomment-55404

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think that did the trick